# Searching Database using LINQ

Tags: vb.net

I have a database table (Access Database) that contains data under OrderNo field.
When user enters new OrderNo, I want to check if that OrderNo already exists or not.
If so, a message should be displayed.

How can I do it using LINQ?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    int searchOrderNo;

    searchOrderNo = 123;

    var q = from t in db.MyTable
            where t.OrderNo.Equals(searchOrderNo)
            select t.OrderNo;

    if (q.Count() > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Value already exists");
    }
```

Apologies, as you are using Access I think you will need to populate a DataSet and then use LINQ over the DataSet rather than querying the Access DB directly.

Comment: Thanks, Do I need to add any libraries?  Also, how to give path of my database?  Should it be in the folder where the application is running from?